# Create new gmail programmatically

Tags: android

I develop an android application and this app uses to send emails so I need create new email in android; Can I create email using android code?

I need create new email from android activity like this:

```
username: [__________]
password: [__________]
SMTP: [__________]
Port: [__________]
SSL/TLS: Dropdown box with 3 options, No, SSL, and TLS
```

Comment: You want to create an e-mail using available gmail account or you want to create a new gmail account?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [using javamail](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android):

```
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

The chap who wrote the code above (not [hd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783412/hd1)) has it on his [github account](https://github.com/tschut/android-javamail-tutorial). Look there or leave a comment if you have further problems.

**UPDATE**

To merely launch gmail, do:

```
Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
startActivity(mailClient);
```